# Limit exceeded on sitemap submission to Yahoo

Tags: sitemap, yahoo

I'm getting an error saying, "Limit exceeded" when I am submitting my sitemap to Yahoo.

Can anyone explain what the error means?

Possible problems:
1. Too many submissions: we certainly don't send the sitemap 5000 times in a day.
2. The sitemap is too big: Our sitemap is a mere 40k file and gzipped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It plainly says on the Yahoo website that it is caused by exceeding 5000 requests in a 24 hour period.
http://developer.yahoo.com/search/rate.html

So, it would seem that it is caused by your program making more than 5,000 requests (perhaps you have a bug)

**NOTE:** It is 5000 requests in 24hours for that specific IP. So if you have shared hosting, and someone else is making requests, they will be adding to your limit.

Answer (score 0):

[www.sitemapwriter.com](http://www.sitemapwriter.com) will give this error on yahoo.  Jut submit the sitemap directly from yahoo's website.

Comment: Explain your answer in brief.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime the "Yahoo Site Explorer" service has been closed, so no more submits are possible on yahoo.

http://developer.yahoo.com/search/siteexplorer/V1/updateNotification.html

And it seems you get a "Limit exceeded" error message now on every submit on the old URL.